# T-SQL - Can I force ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY... to number records from a set point?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I’ve got a table containing a list of patient appointments: the clinic they attended, and the date of their attendance.

I’m trying to write a query that gives me the following:

*‘Which patients attended clinic ‘123-45’ at any point during the period April 2016 – March 2017, and what were the subsequent 2 appointments (the appointment date and clinic attended) for that patient’?*

I’ve tried to come at this by first querying out the list of patient ID numbers for all those patients that attended clinic ‘123-45’ during the time frame, and then putting this list of Patient IDs into a WHERE clause and using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY…`  to give me an ordered list of all appointments for each patient during the 12 month period.

```
    SELECT 
     x.Patient_Id
    ,x.Clinic_Code
    ,x.Appointment_Date
    ,x.Row_No FROM 
    (
    SELECT
         Patient_Id
        ,Clinic_Code
        ,Appointment_Date
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Patient_Id ORDER BY Patient_Id, Appointment_Date asc) [Row_No]

    FROM 
        Appointments

    WHERE 
             Appointment_Date BETWEEN '01/10/2016' AND '30/09/2017'
         AND Patient_ID = 'BLO123'

    ) x

    WHERE x.Row_No < 4
```

**However,** this has the unintended consequence of numbering any appointments that occurred prior to the clinic ‘123-45’ attendance.

So, if the following is my source:

```
Patient_ID | Clinic_Code | Appointment_Date
--------------------------------------------
BLO123     |   QWE-QW    |   01-04-2016
BLO123     |   OPD-ZZ    |   05-10-2016
BLO123     |   123-45    |   13-11-2016
BLO123     |   333-44    |   15-12-2016
BLO123     |   999-45    |   02-02-2017
BLO123     |   222-44    |   15-02-2017
BLO123     |   777-45    |   19-03-2017
```

What I'm trying to get is:

```
Patient_ID | Clinic_Code | Appointment_Date | Row_No
--------------------------------------------------------------
BLO123     |   123-45    |   13-11-2016     |   1
BLO123     |   333-44    |   15-12-2016     |   2
BLO123     |   999-45    |   02-02-2017     |   3
```

But by including the preceding appointments within the date range, I'm instead getting:

```
Patient_ID | Clinic_Code | Appointment_Date | Row_No
--------------------------------------------------------------
BLO123     |   QWE-QW    |   01-04-2016     |   1
BLO123     |   OPD-ZZ    |   05-10-2016     |   2
BLO123     |   123-45    |   13-11-2016     |   3
```

What I would like to query to do is to ignore any clinic appointments that precede the ‘123-45 attendance.
Please can anyone advise if it's possible to do this?

Comment: Off-top; there is a strong argument against using `dd/mm/yyyy` as a [date format](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries), in your where clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach uses a [common table expression (CTE)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) to find the first appointment each patient has at clinic `123-45`.  The main body of the query returns all subsequent appointments.

#### Sample data:

```
DECLARE @Appointment TABLE
    (
        Patient_ID          varchar(6),
        Clinic_code         varchar(6),
        Appointment_Date    date
    )
;

INSERT INTO @Appointment
(
        Patient_ID,
        Clinic_code,
        Appointment_Date
)
VALUES 
    ('BLO123','QWE-QW','20160401'),
    ('BLO123','OPD-ZZ','20161005'),
    ('BLO123','123-45','20161113'),
    ('BLO123','333-44','20161215'),
    ('BLO123','999-45','20170202')
;
```

#### Query:

```
WITH     
    FirstAppointment AS 
    (
        -- Find patients first vist to clinic 123-45.
        SELECT
            Patient_ID,
            MIN(Appointment_Date) AS FirstAppointment_Date
        FROM
            @Appointment
        WHERE
            Appointment_Date >= '20160401'
            AND Appointment_Date <= '20170331'
            AND Clinic_code = '123-45'
        GROUP BY
            Patient_ID
    )    
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.Patient_ID ORDER BY a.Appointment_Date) AS Rn,
    a.*
FROM
    FirstAppointment AS fa
        INNER JOIN @Appointment AS a        ON  a.Patient_ID        = fa.Patient_ID
                                            AND a.Appointment_Date  >= fa.FirstAppointment_Date
;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with foo as
(
select
*
from (values
('BLO123','QWE-QW', cast('20160401' as date))
,('BLO123','OPD-ZZ',cast('20161005' as date))
,('BLO123','123-45',cast('20161113' as date))
,('BLO123','333-44',cast('20161215' as date))
,('BLO123','999-45',cast('20170202' as date))
) a(Patient_ID , Clinic_Code , Appointment_Date)
)
,lags as
(
select 
*
,lag(Clinic_code,1) over (partition by Patient_id order by Appointment_Date) l1
,lag(Clinic_code,2) over (partition by Patient_id order by Appointment_Date) l2
,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Patient_id order by Appointment_Date) rn
from foo
)
select Patient_ID,Clinic_Code,Appointment_Date
,case when Clinic_Code='123-45' then 1
when l1='123-45' then 2
else 3 end  Row_Nr
from lags
where '123-45' in (Clinic_Code,l1,l2)
```

The result:

```
+----------------------------------------------+
|Patient_ID|Clinic_Code|Appointment_Date|Row_No|
+----------------------------------------------+
|BLO123    |123-45     |2016-11-13      |1     |
|BLO123    |333-44     |2016-12-15      |2     |
|BLO123    |999-45     |2017-02-02      |3     |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks, but afraid I'm on SQL Server 2008, and the LAG function isn't available until 2012 apparently.